# NDVI image without filter

Tags: camera, raspicam

Is it possible to create an NDVI heat map from an image that has been taken without a blue filter being used? The images were taken using the NoIR camera on the Raspberry Pi.

Comment: Interesting question, just for others like myself who were wondering what it meant I found NDVI means [Normalized Difference Vegetation Index](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normalized_Difference_Vegetation_Index) on Wikipedia.  I am not clear but to me it seems that you might need two images one with and one without that IR filter (and only the Compute Module has support for two such Pi camera)...